# Exception calling "send" with "1" argument(s): "A recipient must be specified"

Tags: powershell, outlook, smtp

param ([switch]$configure)

$Date = Get-Date

$Server = gc env:computername

## Create e-mail message

$msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage

## Set e-mail properties

$msg.subject = $Subject

## Set e-mail body

$msg.body = $Body

## Creating SMTP server object

$SMTP = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer)

## Email structure

$msg.From = "admin@email.com"

$msg.Replyto = "me@email.com"

$Subject = "Hardware Alert from $Server $Date"

$SMTPServer = "smtp.office365.com"

$SMTPPort = '25'

$SMTPUser = 'admin@email.com'

$SMTPPassword = 'password'

body

else{$smtp.Send($msg)}

I keep getting "a recipient must be specified" when I run this. What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777) and read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Why not just use [send-mailmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1) command?

Answer (score 1):

> I keep getting "a recipient must be specified" when I run this. What am I doing incorrectly?

You did not specify a recipient. (There is no one who could receive that mail.)

The `MailMessage` class not only has a `From` property, but also a `To` property.

```
$msg.To = "someone@somwhere.tld"
```

Check out the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do I go about specifying a recipient? Super new to this.